# Web 8.5 : Content Service v2 endpoint: How to Map Publication IDs to friendly URLs

Tags: web8.5, content-service

We are upgrading Tridion 2013 Content delivery odata service to new Web 8.5 Content Service. After installing the new content service as standalone in my local and hit the content.svc, I noticed it has 2 v2 and v4 version of services and it's not just a end point change for consumers.

After reading other people comments and post, I figure out that consuming applications need to use  /client/v2/content.svc instead of odata.svc but does anyone know how to configure publication id to friendly url for v2 endpoint. SDL live documentation doesn't have any info about these v2 and v4 endpoints.

Appreciate any help!!

https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-901F57EE-AE11-413F-83FF-3BB8695DF4C3